# Delete Nested Objects That Contain Duplicate Properties

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object here

```
{ people: {
    bob: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '561-482-2234'
    },
    jen: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '407-382-3883'
    },
    kim: {
      city: 'new york',
      phone: '607-321-3003'
    }
}}
```

I need to filter this object so that no duplicate cities exist - the end result would be an object containing bob & kim. I am not concerned about ordering or which of the two floridians remains in the object, so it could alternatively be jen & kim

My current implementation contains a for loop that iterates through the people, stores a temporary key and deletes the nested object if the name matches the temporary key. I feel this is a long & drawn out solution

Is there an ES6 method that can achieve this?

Comment: If this is for an arbitrary-level object then you need a recursive function to traverse it. When you self-invoke just pass as an additional parameter an object with the found props. If it's previously found then `delete`.

Comment: why bob and not jen? please add your code.

Comment: So you would just remove "jen" completely? Wouldn't you have a city key with arrays of people objects who live in that city? What should your output look like?

Comment: You can remove duplicates, but you cannot guarantee a specific `name` ends up in the final object since the keys in object have no guaranteed order.

Comment: @NikKyriakides check my 2nd to last statement, I believe that's similar to what I've done

Comment: @adiga that's fine I'm not concerned about who remains in the object

Comment: What if there is a `kim` in florida and `kim` in new york?

Comment: @adiga good question, let's assume all people names are unique and we only care if their city is a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the keys with a `Set` and delete this keys.

```js
var a = { people: { bob: { city: 'florida', phone: '561-482-2234' }, jen: { city: 'florida', phone: '407-382-3883' }, kim: { city: 'new york', phone: '607-321-3003' } } };

Object
    .keys(a.people)
    .filter((s => k => s.has(a.people[k].city) || !s.add(a.people[k].city))(new Set))
    .forEach(k => { delete a.people[k]; });

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce

```js
var a = {
  people: {
    bob: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '561-482-2234'
    },
    jen: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '407-382-3883'
    },
    kim: {
      city: 'new york',
      phone: '607-321-3003'
    }
  }
};
Object.keys(a.people).reduce((acc, e) => {
acc.includes(a.people[e].city) ? delete a.people[e] : acc.push(a.people[e].city);
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(a)
```

Using forEach loop

```js
var a = {
  people: {
    bob: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '561-482-2234'
    },
    jen: {
      city: 'florida',
      phone: '407-382-3883'
    },
    kim: {
      city: 'new york',
      phone: '607-321-3003'
    }
  }
};
var cities = [];
Object.keys(a.people).forEach((e) => {
  if (cities.includes(a.people[e].city))
    delete a.people[e];
  else
    cities.push(a.people[e].city);
})
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Why "*Use a `forEach` loop*"? There's no advantage over the `for` loop. Please explain the meat of your approach.

Comment: added a reduce method too